# health details no longer show up in SBA UI after SpringBoot upgrade

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

I upgraded my apps from SpringBoot 2.1.18 to SpringBoot 2.5.7 and I see that health details such as `diskSpace` no longer show up in SpringBootAdmin UI after the upgrade. I am using SBA 2.0.0 and have not changed that.

The health endpoint still includes them, but the top level key has been renamed from `details` to `components`. I assumed that was what was confusing SBA, but even stranger my custom health indicator still displays in SBA despite this.

Any idea how I can solve this?

**old**

```
{
  "status": "OUT_OF_SERVICE",
  "details": {
    "myCustomHealthIndicator": {
      "status": "OUT_OF_SERVICE",
      "details": {
        "Reason": "Suspect State message received",
        "StateText": "Connection failed; Channel disconnected"
      }
    },
    "diskSpace": {
      "status": "UP",
      "details": {
        "total": 107361579008,
        "free": 94436716544,
        "threshold": 10485760
      }
    },
    "refreshScope": {
      "status": "UP"
    }
  }
}
```

**new**

```
{
  "status": "OUT_OF_SERVICE",
  "components": {
    "diskSpace": {
      "status": "UP",
      "details": {
        "total": 107361579008,
        "free": 100102447104,
        "threshold": 10485760,
        "exists": true
      }
    },
    "livenessState": {
      "status": "UP"
    },
    "ping": {
      "status": "UP"
    },
    "readinessState": {
      "status": "UP"
    },
    "myCustomHealthIndicator": {
      "status": "OUT_OF_SERVICE",
      "details": {
        "Reason": "Suspect State message received",
        "StateText": "Connection failed; Channel disconnected"
      }
    }
  },
  "groups": [
    "liveness",
    "readiness"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by upgrading to Spring Boot Admin Server 2.5.4 ( `de.codecentric:spring-boot-admin-starter-server:jar:2.5.4` )